# Rsync ignores folders ending in slashes

Tags: shell, rsync

I have this following content in a file named "/rsync/include.txt"

```
+ /home/**
+ /opt**
- *
```

I then call the `rsync` command as follows:

```
rsync -avr --include-from="/rsync/include.txt" . ../backup
```

This produces the following output:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory ../archive
./
opt/
opt/some-file
opt/include-me/
opt/include-me/me-too
opt/include-me/and-me/

sent 299 bytes  received 106 bytes  810.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

The `/home` directory exists, and contains files.

Why does the `+ /home/**` pattern not work? I do not want to use the `+ /home**` pattern, as that could match other folder names, e.g., `/homeopathy`.

Can anybody help me understand why this command doesn't work, and point me in the direction of the working command?

**EDIT**: While I'd still like an answer to this question, I sincerely suggest using `rdiff-backup` as it uses similar filtering files and patterns, but is substantially easier to use. I've spent a good deal of time today on this issue with `rsync`, which was resolved in a few minutes using `rdiff-backup`.

Comment: @rkta ...that's a joke right? I'm supposed to write in every single folder in the `/home` directory? There's absolutely no recursive way of doing this? Why is rsync still in use?

Comment: Right! Okay. So is that to suggest that having the rule `+ */` before `- *` should rectify this? I'll try now and get back to you with my results.

Comment: @rkta Nope - now I'm in the boat of a ton of directories I didn't specify with a `+`  rule are included in the output. So currently the man page seems to suggest the solution is go through and manually copy each directory name? I might as well copy every folder by hand. Surely this isn't the only way, otherwise nobody would use `rsync`.

Comment: @rkta This doesn't resolve using a file to list the exclusions and inclusions, which is a big requirement for me unfortunately. So with that in mind, `rsync` isn't a suitable solution to my problem because it just isn't easy enough to use. `rdiff-backup` provided the expected syntax and Just Worked™.

Comment: @rkta It's similar, but it is certainly different in that non-CLI users can write the file without caring for syntax. It's also very troublesome to have to convert `some/file/path/*` to `--include="some/file/path/*"` for every single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General debugging info

The easiest way to see if your filter rules do what you want, is to use `-vv` (increase verbosity twice) in combination with `-n` (dry-run).

With double verbosity you will see which pattern caused which file to be ignored.
You may `grep` the output to only see the relevant parts.

**Example**

```
%  rsync -avv --include 'opt/1' --exclude 'opt/*' -n ./ /tmp  \
    | grep '\[sender\]'
[sender] showing directory opt/1 because of pattern opt/1
[sender] hiding directory opt/2 because of pattern opt/*
[sender] hiding directory opt/3 because of pattern opt/*
```

---

### Specific answer

Your example fails because `+ /home/**` is excluded by `- *`.

[man rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) states:

> Note that, when using the --recursive (-r) option (which is implied by -a), every subdir component of every path is visited left to right, with each directory having a chance for exclusion before its content.

So the pattern `/home/**` will be evaluated after `/home` is traversed, but this will never happen, because `- *` excludes `/home`.

To include `/home/` you just have to insert it before `/home/**`, so your exclude file becomes:

```
+ /home/
+ /home/**
+ /opt/
+ /opt/**
- *
```

Comment: Aggghhhhh I had tried `+ /home \n + /home/**`, but that extra trailing forward-slash was all that was needed. How frustrating is the filter syntax! Learned a lot about reading man pages more carefully from this experience. So many thanks for all your help @rkta